# OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'example.example_field' in 'field list'")

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-models, mysql-python

My `Example` model used to have a decimal field `example_field` defined as:

```py
sample_field = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=3, blank=True, null=True)
```

I decided to remove this field from `Example` model and everywhere in the code that I used `example_object.example_field`. After `makemigrations` and `migrate`, everything worked well and I made a pull request to a remote branch.

Then I switched to another local branch and got this error:

```py
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'example.example_field' in 'field list'")
```

It makes sense becuase this branch still uses `example_object.example_field`. However, after the remote branch accepted the pull request. I still got the same error after pulling from the remote branch.

Remote branch was deployed on AWS after accepting the PR. One of the two instances was working fine, but the other one had the same `OperationalError`.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace to your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In either circumstance (AWS or local branch), the first step is to make sure that your updated code is, in fact, deployed on the instance properly.

1. Navigate to to your project

   ```
   cd /path/to/django/project
   ```
2. Check the `Example` class definition in the file:

   ```
   grep -A20 'class Example\(' models.py
   ```
3. Verify that your field has, in fact, been removed from the code on both instances or your local branch.
4. Do a global search in your project for use of `example_field`:

   ```
   cd /path/to/django/project
   find . -name '*.py' | xargs grep -Ri example_field
   ```
5. Remove all pyc files and restart your app server:

   ```
   cd /path/to/django/project
   find . -name '*.pyc' -delete
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! It totally works! After applying `grep -A20 'class Example' models.py` and `find . -name '*.py' | xargs grep -Ri example_field ` I found repo wasn't updated appropriately.